# Partitioning a list to several depths

Tags: list-manipulation, partitions

I an aware of the `Partition` command which partitions a list into sublists. I'm curious as to whether there is an efficient way to partition a list several times over in one step. For example, can I turn the list

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
```

into the list

```
{{{1,2},{3,4}},{{5,6},{7,8}}}
```

through one use of the `Partition` command instead of two (or indeed any command). In actual fact, I'll be going to a list of many levels of nested lists, which is why I'm keen to know the answer. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try [`ArrayReshape`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReshape.html):

```
ArrayReshape[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {2, 2, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}
> ```

or `Fold`+ `Partition`:

```
Fold[Partition, Range[8], {2, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}
> ```

or `Nest` + `Partition`:

```
Nest[Partition[#, 2] &, Range @ 8, 2]
```

> ```
>  {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}
> ```

There is also the (undocumented) 6-argument of form of `Partition`:

```
Partition[Range @ 8, 4, 4, 1, {}, Partition[{##}, 2] &]
```

> ```
>  {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}
> ```